# how to create a filter form for a Microsoft Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am fairly new to Access. I am trying to create a filter pre-report form. On this form, the user will be asked for a start and end date. He will also be given a list of Item names which are found in a different form/table and will have the ability to check off which items the report should filter on.

Do I need to use a subform for this? I tried one out, but I can't see how to add checkboxes, it seems to just give me a list and I can't modify the subform.

What I really think I need to do is to populate a checkbox list with all of the items in the other table. How exactly would I do this (if its really the best solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular form for this.  You do not need to bind it to a table.  Just drop 2 textboxes on the form, and as many checkboxes as you feel you need.

The report will be based on a query, which in turn will be based on this form.  All the fields will be brought into the query and will reference the controls on the form.

For instance, let's say you have 2 textboxes on the form; one called txtStartDate and one called txtEndDate.  The form will be called frmReportFilter.  In the query that's driving the report, pull in your date column and in the Criteria put >=Forms!frmReportFilter!txtStartDate.  This will pull in all records where your date field is greater than or equal to whatever is in the Start Date textbox.  The rest will be referenced similarly.

Comment: Thats fine for the start and end dates. But for the checkboxes, I can't hard code them. The list will vary based on a different (Inventory) table. How can I list all of the items from that table on this new form, each preceded with a checkbox?

Comment: For the list of checkboxes, you'll probably need to do that in code.  Perform a loop, check each checkbox value and if it's true then add that item to the list.  In the end, you'll have a string like: "Tomatoes, Grapes, Apples".  Then just pass that string into a SQL using IN, (i.e. SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Item IN (" & MyItemList & ")